# How can I get my own status bar below a Map fragment in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I'm trying to get a google map to occupy almost all the screen, but I want my own full width status bar at the bottom of the screen underneath the map.  To do this, I'm trying to use a LinearLayout, with a TextView for the status bar.  However the status bar never appears.  My xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />             

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/main_status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding = "4sp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Statusbar"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm mildly concerned that there are are only two choices for `android:layout_height`, namely `"wrap_content"` and `"match_parent"`.  This doesn't seem to allow the specification of the status bar to be the size it needs (i.e. `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`), and with the map taking the rest, because to me using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` logically implies there's no room for anything else.  However, even using

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

for both doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with the status bar: but does `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` (in the Manifest) may help you? If you just wan't navigation and stuff there you could do this :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @tenhouse, however the answer shows that I had the wrong xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

If I had to guess, `wrap_content` isn't working for the `MapFragment`. Beyond that, your layout doesn't specify what you apparently want, anyway.

> I'm mildly concerned that there are are only two choices for android:layout_height, namely "wrap_content" and "match_parent".

There are an infinite number of choices for `android:layout_height`, as it can also take a dimension, and there are an infinite number of positive integers.

> This doesn't seem to allow the specification of the status bar to be the size it needs (i.e. android:layout_height="wrap_content"), and with the map taking the rest

Set `android:layout_height` of the fragment to be `0dp`, and set its `android:layout_weight="1"`. This tells Android to allocate 0 pixels for the intrinsic height, but to also give it all leftover pixels (since the bar's weight will be 0 by default). This will cause the `MapFragment` to take over all space not consumed by your bottom bar.

Comment: thanks very much, that works :-).  And sorry if my question was stuipd, I'm such a duffer at this Android xml stuff

Comment: @Stochastically: The question wasn't stupid, though the phrasing suggested that you were pretty confident in your assertion regarding the valid values for `android:layout_height`. I needed to call you on that in order to give you the solution (last paragraph). I could have handled that more gently, and I apologize for any ruffled feathers. I further apologize if the insinuation that you might indeed have feathers ruffled them. :-)